# Efficient Mergesort Confusion

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, while-loop, mergesort

I have been reading a [mergesort example](http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/merge/mergen.htm) (the efficient one) since yesterday and I still can't understand how it works despite looking at the code:

```
private static void sort(int[] list) {
    a = list;
    int n = a.length;
    // according to variant either/or:
    b = new int[n];
    b = new int[(n + 1) / 2];
    mergesort(0, n - 1);
}

private static void mergesort(int first, int last) {
    if (first < last) {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;
        mergesort(first, mid);
        mergesort(mid + 1, last);
        merge(first, mid, last);
    }
}
```

No problem understanding the algorithm up until this point but the confusion is in the following method:

```
private static void merge(int first, int mid, int last) {
    int i, j, k;

    i = 0;
    j = first;

    while (j <= mid)
        b[i++] = a[j++]; // *j's value is now mid*

    i = 0; // *i is reset to 0, nothing's been done to j*
    k = first;


    // *before entering the following while loop, j still carries mid's value*
    while (k < j && j <= last)
        if (b[i] <= a[j])
            a[k++] = b[i++];
        else
            a[k++] = a[j++];        

    // copy back remaining elements of first half (if any)
    while (k < j)
        a[k++] = b[i++];
}
```

Entering the second while loop `while (k < j && j <= last)` is where I don't understand how this sorting works. From what I understood, the first half of the array `a` is already copied to the auxiliary array `b`, and now we want to arrange the entire array by comparing `a[j++]` (the second half) to the auxiliary array `b[i++]` so that we can get the smaller array element and place it in array `a` to sort the array in ascending order.

But why `while (k < j && j <= last)`? `k < j` sounds logical enough because we need to get all the values back from the auxiliary array but why `j <= last`? And why can't we just do `while (k <= last)` ?

And also, could somebody please affirm that my understanding of j's value in the above code is correct?

Comment: The " can be removed from the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`k < j`   denotes that auxillary array **b** still contains elements

`j <= last`  denotes that the second part of **a** still contains elements

We cannot use `k <= last` here, because we may access array **a** indexes beyond the border, when j becomes last+1

Too long for comments, added here:

This variant is useful when available memory is limited (large dataset). It is mentioned in some tutorials (I've met it in J.Bucknall book about algorithms in Delphi). It is stable ( if (b[i] **<=** a[j]) holds stability. It is usually not faster, because it is better not to copy data at all , but, for example, 'trigger' source and destination array (pointers) at every stage

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd also like to ask - how common is the merge sort above? I went through a lot of mergesort tutorials, none of which mentioned the construction of second array being only half the size of original array to make it more efficient. Is such implementation done at the cost of stability? Most importantly, is this really faster?

Comment: Also, can we say that k < j denotes that **there is still elements unsorted and not placed**? Because k will never reach j unless the last element has been in place.

Comment: 2nd question - yes, you are right. 1t question - added in the answer